# Use Bash Perl to fetch substring off of command output

Tags: linux, bash, perl, substring

Let's presume the text I'm working with is (which is outputted by `pecl install xdebug`):

```
  |   - A list of all settings:  https://xdebug.org/docs-settings.php    |
  |   - A list of all functions: https://xdebug.org/docs-functions.php   |
  |   - Profiling instructions:  https://xdebug.org/docs-profiling2.php  |
  |   - Remote debugging:        https://xdebug.org/docs-debugger.php    |
  |                                                                      |
  |                                                                      |
  |   NOTE: Please disregard the message                                 |
  |       You should add "extension=xdebug.so" to php.ini                |
  |   that is emitted by the PECL installer. This does not work for      |
  |   Xdebug.                                                            |
  |                                                                      |
  +----------------------------------------------------------------------+


running: find "/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserNxuIJy/install-xdebug-2.9.2" | xargs ls -dils
1078151    4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Feb  3 17:40 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserNxuIJy/install-xdebug-2.9.2
1078337    4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Feb  3 17:40 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserNxuIJy/install-xdebug-2.9.2/usr
1078338    4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Feb  3 17:40 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserNxuIJy/install-xdebug-2.9.2/usr/local
1078339    4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Feb  3 17:40 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserNxuIJy/install-xdebug-2.9.2/usr/local/lib
1078340    4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Feb  3 17:40 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserNxuIJy/install-xdebug-2.9.2/usr/local/lib/php
1078341    4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Feb  3 17:40 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserNxuIJy/install-xdebug-2.9.2/usr/local/lib/php/extensions
1078342    4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Feb  3 17:40 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserNxuIJy/install-xdebug-2.9.2/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731
1078336 2036 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2084800 Feb  3 17:40 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserNxuIJy/install-xdebug-2.9.2/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so

Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/xdebug-2.9.2
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so" to php.ini
```

I want to extract this part off of this output and save it in a variable for later use:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so
```

I have attempted doing it like this with Perl without success:

```
echo $OUTPUT | perl -lne 'm/You should add "(.*)"/; print $1'
```

How do I get the substring dynamically with perl? What's the pattern that I need to use?

Comment: `variable=$(echo $OUTPUT | grep "enter text here" | cut -d'"' -f2` maybe?

Comment: I need help with the pattern as I can't grab the path from the output. The actual logic to contain it into a variable isn't a problem

Comment: you're printing `$1` for every line, which is initially undefined, then `"extension=xdebug.so"` after line 8, until 29, when it's going to be what you need.
You need to print only when the match is successful, and you need to refine the match to match only zend_extension

Comment: Not clear where OP is interested in a line starting with `You should add` or just anything that has `zend_extension=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `$OUTPUT` text placed in a file `output.txt`

```
cat output.txt | perl -wnE'say $1 if /You should add "(zend_extension=.*)"/'
```

This uses the specifics of the shown text, in particular the seemingly unique `zend_extension=...` preface for the path, to distinguish the needed line from an earlier "*You should add*" pattern.  Change as needed, to what is more suitable for your problem.

If the text is thrown at the one-liner as one string in your code then add `-0777` flag to test.

Otherwise please clarify how that `$OUTPUT` comes about.

---

Tested with a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Last modified: 2020 Feb 03 (12:58)

OUTPUT=$(cat "output.txt")

echo $OUTPUT | perl -wnE'say $1 if /You should add "(zend_extension=.*)"/'
```

where `output.txt` is a file with the text from the question, and the right line is printed.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear about that. By `$OUTPUT` I basically meant: `OUTPUT=$(pecl install xdebug)`. Does that make sense?

Comment: It works with `cat`, but not with echo, like so: `echo $OUTPUT | perl -wnE 'say $1 if /You should add "(zend_extension=.*)"/'`. I'm using Debian 10

Comment: @Dugi So I've now used a basic bash script, in which I do `OUTPUT=$(cat "output.txt")`, where _"output.txt"_ is a file in which I copy-pasted your text from the question. Then I copy-paste the one-liner from this answer into `echo $OUTPUT | perl...` -- and it works, it prints to screen the line of interest.  How is this different from your situation?  (I can't do that `pecl` thing but it shouldn't matter)

Comment: @Dugi Added the statement from the above comment to the post

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `perl`:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /You should add "(?!extension=xdebug\.so)([^"]+)"/' <<< "$OUTPUT"
```

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so
```

Negative lookahead `(?!extension=xdebug\.so)` will ignore line `extension=xdebug.so` in output.

**Alternatively** you may match `You should add` at the line start:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /^You should add "([^"]+)"/' <<< "$OUTPUT"
```

Comment: negative lookahead is overkill here

Comment: Yes that's why have an alternate solution also

Answer (score 0):

Probably OP meant to use

`echo $OUTPUT | perl -ne 'm/You should add "(.*)"/ && print $1'`

or

`echo $OUTPUT | perl -ne 'print $1 if m/You should add "(.*)"/'`